# Investing in followers and growing their power

Tags: dnd-5e, followers-and-hirelings

I've got two NPCs that are my followers (so far). I have a powerful spellbook my DM gave me, however many of the spells are not on my Warlock's spell list, so I can't make spell scrolls out of them. My followers are also not able to cast spells and even if they could, they're so low level they wouldn't be able to use half the book to make scrolls for me. I also generally want to hold their loyalty and increase their power (maybe two birds with one stone there).

Assuming I know how to acquire followers, how can I invest in them to make them more powerful for my own ends (RAW)? Can I direct their learning in ways that give me control over how they level up and whether or not they learn to cast spells? Adding them to the party may be out of the question, since I think it's a pretty big effect on the party for just one player's story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Followers

There is a large section on followers starting on p. 92 of the Dungeon Master's Guide.

**Control**

Of relevance:

> NPCs ... might follow the
> adventurers because of a **bond of loyalty, gratitude,
> or love**. **Such NPCs are controlled by you [the DM]**, or you
> can transfer control to the players. Even if a player
> controls an NPC, it's up to you to **make sure the NPC is
> portrayed as a character in his or her own right**, not just
> as a servant that the players can manipulate for their
> own benefit.

NPCs are not automatons under the control of the PC; they are individuals who want and aspire to whatever the DM decides they want and aspire to. The PC can influence them in the ways a person can influence any other person: friendship, loyalty, reward, punishment etc. You could encourage them to take certain classes or feats but ultimately the DM decides if that is what they want to do.

**More power**

> Adding them to the party may be out of the question ...

Well you have a problem there because generally NPCs only gain XP when adventuring with the party:

> Any NPC that accompanies the adventurers acts as
> a party member and earns a full share of experience
> points.

**Loyalty**

There is an optional loyalty system in the section of followers in the DMG. Suffice to say, if you are nice to them they get more loyal; if you are nasty they get less loyal.

### Misconceptions in your prelude

**Making magic items**

> ... I can't make spell scrolls out of them

Creating magic items (even spell scrolls) by players is an entirely optional rule:

> As an option, you can allow player characters to craft magic items.

So you need to have the DM's permission and note that for anything above 3rd level they start to get prohibitively expensive.

**Using spell scrolls**

> ... to make scrolls for me.

Uh uh. Even if they can turn the spells into scrolls you still can't use them if they are not on your list (DMG p. 200):

> If the spell is on your class's spell list
> you can use an action to read the scroll and cast its spell
> without having to provide any of the spell's components
> **Otherwise, the scroll is unintelligible.**

Comment: I'm aware that I can't use the scrolls, but that doesn't make them without worth :)

Comment: @TomSterkenburg the cost to make them is basically prohibitive to making a profit. This isn't 3.5 where you can become market lords by making magic items and sell them in the inter-dimensional bazaar.

Comment: Same logic still applies, they have worth